# python pandas - summing up two variables with different formats

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum up two variables using following code.

```
data['C'] = data['A'] + data['B']
```

My data has two variables A and B. A is in datetime format and B is object. I tried to convert B to datetime format using to_datetime but it's giving me error.

PS: B variable doesn't have consistent data.

PFB sample data attached as image.

How can I sum up A and B.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: Do not attach sample data as image, type it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert column `B` if integer values are `days`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['2012-03-04','2012-11-30','2014-01-25'], 
                     'B':[7,7,'111 days 00:00:00']})
data.A = pd.to_datetime(data.A)
print (data))
           A                  B
0 2012-03-04                  7
1 2012-11-30                  7
2 2014-01-25  111 days 00:00:00

data.B = pd.to_timedelta(data.B, unit='D')
data['C'] = data.A + data.B
print (data)
           A        B          C
0 2012-03-04   7 days 2012-03-11
1 2012-11-30   7 days 2012-12-07
2 2014-01-25 111 days 2014-05-16
```